# Pageblocktable not showing records

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, pageblocktable

I'm querying Task record from contructor and displaying in Pageblocktable but it's not displaying records in Pageblock table. Could you please let me know what went wrong?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myControllerExtension">
{!tasklist}
<apex:pageBlock title="Related Activities">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Activity" collapsible="false">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tasklist}" var="t" > 
            <apex:outputText label="Id" value="{!t.Subject}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

```
public class myControllerExtension {
public Account acct {get;set;}
public List<Task> tasklist  {get;set;}

public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    tasklist = [Select Id, Subject from Task limit 20];     
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in below line of your code:

```
 <apex:outputText label="Id" value="{!t.Subject}"/>
```

Please check below code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myControllerExtensionss">
<apex:pageBlock title="Related Activities">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Activity" collapsible="false">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tasklist}" var="t" > 
            <apex:column value="{!t.Subject}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Apex controller:

```
public class myControllerExtensionss {
public List<Task> tasklist  {get;set;}
public Account acct {get;set;}
public myControllerExtensionss(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    tasklist=new List<Task>();
    acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    tasklist = [Select Id, Subject from Task limit 20];     
}}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot . It's working.

Comment: You are welcome Ashish